# Unusual deadlock occuring

Tags: sql-server, performance, deadlock, deadlock-graph

I have spent a few days trying to debug a deadlock that occurs in production. This is one I didn't understand however.
Below is pseudo code for the stored procedure. The stored procedure generates a deadlock with another instance of itself.

I know that the code is not brilliant, this old code on the system. But I want to understand why this deadlocks. The graph always shows the second selects deadlocking.

The first select performs a table scan, so I believe that places click on all rows in table.

I'd have thought this would queue one stored procedure behind the other. I cannot recreate this after days if trying.

```
Begin tran

Begin tran

Set isolation level repeatable read

//This select does a table scan, so I believe does X lock on all rows

Select a,b,c
From queuetable with(xlock, rowlock)
Where a = x

Delete from queuetable
Where a = X

Commit tran

Begin tran 

//Get oldest row - this is the deadlocking query

Select top 1 a,b,c
From queuetable
Order by b

//Mark row to be processed
Update queuetable
Set c=processing
Where a = y

Commit tran

Commit tran
```

Comment: Repeatable read is the culprit here. I had faced similar scenario, changed that to read committed and issue is gone to a majority extent.

Comment: Is there a reason for the nested transactions? The inner BEGIN/COMMIT has no effect... (There are no such things as subtransactions in SQL Server - nested transactions are only in syntax, not semantics.)

Comment: There is no reason for the nested transaction, it's old code and one of the things I will remove. I believe the repeatable read is the problem, however I want to understand why. The first select does a table scan and uses click, rowlock, which I think means all the rows have to be scanned and that all rows are given and X lock. Therefore the other instance should queue at the first select.

Comment: Do you by any chance have the deadlock xml? Adding that could help in explaining.

Comment: Maybe, you should add `HOLDLOCK` hint on your select query, so that locks are held until a transaction is completed.

Comment: I thought because I have repeatable read on the locks are held to the end of the transaction?

Comment: You should update your question with deadlock graph. You can extract it from system_health*.xel or set now trace flag 1222 globally to catch future deadlocks in errorlog

Answer (score -1):

Try without the first BEGIN TRAN and last COMMIT TRAN.

If you are using a stored procedure, the procedure itself already creates a transaction.

Your transaction locks because of the following script:

```
//This select does a table scan, so I believe does X lock on all rows
Select a,b,c
From queuetable with(xlock, rowlock)
Where a = x
```

From what I see in the script, the `with(xlock, rowlock)` is not needed.

Try with the following script:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

-- This select does a table scan, so I believe does X lock on all rows
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM queuetable
 WHERE a = x

DELETE queuetable
 WHERE a = X

-- Get oldest row - this is the deallocking query
SELECT TOP 1 a, b, c
  FROM queuetable
 ORDER BY b

-- Mark row to be processed
UPDATE queuetable
   SET c = processing
 WHERE a = y
```

Comment: I have tried this but that causes more deadlocks earlier on at the delete. 2 instances do the select getting compatible shares lock. However because of the repeatable read they both when one tries to delete the select lock is escalated to a X lock so the read is repeatable in the transaction. However, it can't go on to delete because the over instance also wants an X lock on the select so it's repeatable. Neither can move on and we deadlock.

Comment: Hi Dan, roger that. Can you please tell why do you need both SELECT?

Comment: First select is find current item that's has finished processing. The delete this. That could all be in the delete itself I know, as I say old code someone else wrote. Second select is get next oldest item in queue to process. The system is multi threaded at app level.

Comment: Ok, but you can change the script right? The "old code someone wrote" is not excuse. In my opinion you need to rethink the script based on what you need. I think that you don't need to SELECT the table in this script operation. Are you showing this data in some view or saving it in a model?